# Can't import provider in firebase 9.1.3 with GoogleAuthProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am trying to implement Firebase 9.1.3 in a Next.js application. It seems everything is fine, until the code reaches the provider and sends an error: "can't import provider" when I call Firebase from another component. This is the code I have used to create Firebase logic.

```
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
```

This are my imports in firebase.js

```
const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig):getApp();


const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth();
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();


export default { db, auth, provider };
```

The error appears in `const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();` when I try to import provider in my login page. Now I have noticed I cannot import auth, so I imagine I can't import db too.

Comment: Can you share the file where you are importing this? Also try removing default from export

Comment: @Dharmaraj lol i have removed default and now it seems to work